# wp_enqueue_scripts in TinyMCE Modal

Tags: wordpress, dialog, modal-dialog, tinymce

I'm creating a simple WordPress plugin that requires wp_enqueue_media() to be called from a TinyMCE pop up in order to upload and/or select an image.

The issue im having is wp_enqueue_media() and wp_enqueue_script() don't appear to work with the TinyMCE pop up modal.

I am including wp-load.php in my modal window.

Is there a way to utilize native WordPress script loading within a TinyMCE modal?

Here is an example of what I am doing.
http://return-true.com/adding-tinymce-button-to-wordpress-via-plugin-part-2/

Comment: I guess the problem is that the modal content is in an iframe. Did you consider using an linline TinyMCE modal that do not use an iframe? E.g., WooCommerce Shortcodes plugin uses inline modals.

Answer (score 2):

Like I already said in my comment, I think the best approach is to use an inline modal (no iframe).

It is very simple: using the 1st part of the article (http://return-true.com/adding-tinymce-button-to-wordpress-via-a-plugin/) as a basis, just replace the JavaScript with the following (copied from [TinyMCE guidelines](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/)):

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor) {
        // Add a button that opens a window
        editor.addButton('example', {
            text: 'Example',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Example plugin',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Title'}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                        editor.insertContent('Title: ' + e.data.title);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

After that, you have a simple modal, with no iframe, thus using the native Wordpress script loading.

If the content must be in an iframe (which I doubt), one option is to create a 'blank' page in Wordpress with a page template of its own and use that page as the modal content. I actually tested that it works, but it is clearly more complicated (requires something like a blog post to explain).

Comment: Thank you. I realise this post is almost 2 years old but I spent a day trying to figure this out and yours is the only info I found for this exact scenario. How does this windowManager fit in with just using a bootstrap or jQuery modal?
There is plenty of info in TinyMCE docs on using modals but not specific to Wordpress Customizer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not including `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in the modal window html.

Adding these functions solved the enqueue issues.